# php - prevent using the same coupon code twice in paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal, coupon

The scenario is pretty simple.

In an e-commerce site, a certain user is given a coupon code and he can use it only once. Coupons are stored in database against each user's id.

Suppose the user adds a few products in the cart to make an order and enters the coupon and then clicks on the 'Pay Now' button and is redirected to the Paypal site for payment.

But the user uses a trick and does not pay just at that moment for the order he has just made. Instead he goes on to make another order by adding few other products in his cart and then again uses the single-time coupon and clicks the payment button to go to the Paypal site.

Now he makes payment for both the orders one after another and thus becomes successful to reuse the single-time coupon.

How to prevent the user from reusing the single-time coupon ? Should it take place before he is taken to the Pyapal site or after he is taken there ? and how above all?

Comment: is coupon handled by you?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your coupon codes have two states, "used" and "unused" ..add a third state, "pending." When the user puts the coupon code in, validate it then mark it as pending. Once payment is confirmed mark it as "used" and don't let the user enter it again. If the user cancels their order you can make the coupon code "unused" again.

Comment: what if the user just closes the Paypal site without cancelling the payment?

Comment: Do you want to prevent users from using a coupon with a 'pending' status ? Suppose a coupon is marked as pending and the user clicks the payment button and is taken to the Paypal site for payment .What if the user just closes the Paypal site  without making any payment  and then begins adding products in cart to make a second order and enters the coupon again ? He should be allowed to use the coupon , right ? The OP describes it well I think.

Comment: You don't validate it once it's set to pending. Once it's pending you either wait 24 hours to set it back to unused or it gets set used when payment is confirmed. Add an event handler to the Pay Now button that does an ajax request to a script that validates the coupon code before sending the user to payPal.

Comment: 1) So as to the Patypal window closing scenario, do you want to make the coupon unusable for another 24 hours ? Is that practical ?  2) If the Paypal site opened for the first order is still kept open without having made the payment and the user makes another order, then coupon will be available for use again, right ?

Comment: hang on i'm making a fiddle

Comment: If you don't want to wait 24 hours you can always use AJAX to check and see if the coupon was processed before sending it again. I just realized i can't make a fiddle because I can;t do the PHP end in a fiddle. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92872/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-pamblam).

Comment: what to check through ajax ? Go through the 2 cases described in the OP?

Comment: i'm at work i can't really chat right now, but you can write a PHP script that uses the paypal API to check payments. You can use AJAX to check that script to see if payment has been processed. It's been a while since I've actually used the Paypal API, but you should be able to pass arbitrary data through paypal that can identify if the coupon code was used or not. all that is really outside of the scope of this question, but if you have questions about any specific aspect of that you can always ask a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

In case coupon is handled by you,

you can create single table, 2 columns:

coupon_id <-- primary key
order_id <-- probably you want this to be unique.

then you store coupon there, or if coupon is already there, you are checking if it is for same order_id.

Is this helping? Please comment and I will improve the answer.

Comment: E-commerce admin generates the coupons beforehand. So no way to assign a coupon against a particular order in the way you said .

Comment: coupon will be generated. then when user do purchase, he will enter the coupon, and then *after* you verify the coupon, you will insert it into the table.

Comment: is coupon entered in paypal or on your site?

Comment: coupons exist as pre-generated in database. 'and then after you verify the coupon, you will insert it into the table' - go through the 2 cases described in the OP.

Comment: probably I do not understand the question but let me try to explain what I mean. you have 2 tables. first with coupons. second is coupon-order_id. The user make a purchase, have coupon and enter it on the site (before payment). server verify that this is valid coupon, and insert it in the second table "coupon-order_id". If the coupon is inserted, everything is OK. If coupon is not inserted, a select is made and is checked if this coupon have record for same order_id. This can happen if "F5" is hit. notice, because of primary key, there can be only one row with single coupon. Is this help?